# How can we say "I have not seen a righteous man foresaken . . ."?

Tags: blessing, tehilim-psalms, bentching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I never saw a tzaddik be abandoned…” - how do we understand this?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/i-never-saw-a-tzaddik-be-abandoned-how-do-we-understand-this)

Rabbi Emanuel Feldman, shlita, in the January 23, 2013, issue of Mishpacha gave his list of the ten most intriguing Torah questiosn.  This is number 9:
"At the end of bircas hamazon, we repeat the following phrase from Psalm 37:25:  "I was young and became old, and I have not seen a righteous man forsaken, and his children begging for bread."  How can King David say this when we do, in fact, see righteous people suffering and their children going hungry?

Comment: Duplicate? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3772/1569